# Boto3 error with logging handler

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am getting this error when I try to import the boto3 library. I have installed boto3 1.4.1 and also tried downgrading to 1.3.1 and still I am getting this below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "storage.py", line 1, in <module>
    import boto3
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/boto3/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from boto3.session import Session
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/boto3/session.py", line 17, in <module>
    import botocore.session
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    class NullHandler(logging.Handler):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Handler'
```

Answer (score 10):

I've found that this can happen when a file named `logging.py` exists in the same directory as your Python script (`storage.py`). This is because Boto3 tries to import the logging module, but it imports `logging.py` instead.

To fix, move or rename `logging.py`, or move your Python script.