# Cloud9 Python attribute error (module 'logging' has no attribute 'info')

Tags: python, boto3, attributeerror, cloud9

I'm new to Python. Was following some videos last week where we were translating a string from English to French. That went fine. I moved on and was following other videos and now I keep getting this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/ec2-user/environment/Python_AWS/create_S3_bucket.py", line 3, in <module>
> import boto3
> File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/boto3/**init**.py", line 14, in <module>
> import logging
> File "/home/ec2-user/environment/Python_AWS/logging.py", line 39, in <module>
> logging.info("The Source Language and Target Language codes are different - proceeding") # This will not print to the console because it is lower than warning
> AttributeError: module 'logging' has no attribute 'info'

Here is the code I'm trying to run:

```
import boto3

aws_resource = boto3.resource("s3")

# Name the bucket uniquely, no spaces
bucket = aws_resource.Bucket("test-bucket-198538723")

response = bucket.create(
    ACL='public-read', #for private bucket, change 'public-read' to 'private'
    CreateBucketConfiguration={
        'LocationConstraint': 'us-east-2'
    },
    
)

print(response)
```

I'm not even using logging in my code. It seems like it's referencing my old code file where I was translating language, but that file isn't even open. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried running different code and some run, and some give me the same error, for code also not using logging.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Boto3 error with logging handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40463962/boto3-error-with-logging-handler)

Comment: Nevermind, my coach helped my fix it. I had a file with "logging" in the file name so it kept reference that file. After changing the name of the file to remove "logging" from it, it all works now. Lesson learned. Is there a way for me to mark this question as answered?